# MySQL Connect "Cost"?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

Let's say we have a db class (in PHP - but it should be relevant in any language), that opens a connection to the MySQL server each time there's a query.  Some scripts will query the db once per execution, some twice, up to maybe 4 or 5 different queries in the same execution.

Is there any way to know of how bad it would be on the MySQL server if we closed the connection each time a query was executed (vs keeping it open for the duration of the script)?

I've tried reading the documentation but I haven't been able to figure out which one is worse in terms of performance and load on the MySQL server.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question, but why close the connection in between in the first place?

Comment: Just curious: _Why_ you close the connection after every single query?

Comment: We're getting a lot of sleeping connections after script execution, even when we explicitly close the connection.  These sleeping connections linger, and sometimes result in a too many connections issue.  (We permit 2000 open connections and it still runs out -- not always, but enough to make it an issue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's pretty bad for performance, creating a database connection takes some time.

You usually extended the lifetime of the database connections so they kept open between requests and gets reused. Reconnecting to the database for *each* query would be *very* silly.

Answer (score 2):

You should connect once upon first query and close it at the end of the page (PHP does this automatically anyways). Why add more overhead by closing and re-opening the connection every time?

Answer (score 1):

Connection should be opened and closed, so it's just additional unnecessary connection between (PHP) and MySql server. So don't close connection every time query is executed.

Additionally, I see **NO** reason for that